# No response from Bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to write a command for my telegram bot. however I am not getting a response. Where could I be making a mistake. Below is the code. I am using the node-api.

```js
'use strict'

var tg = require('telegram-node-bot')('mytoken')

tg.router.
    when(['/start'], 'StartController')

tg.controller('StartController', ($) => {
    tg.for('/start', () => {
        tg.sendMessage('Hi, welcome to my bot!')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are not passing the `chat_id` parameter in the `sendMessage` method. An easier method would be to substitute the `tg` variable with a `$`. This automatically passes in the `chat_id`. See correction below.

```js
'use strict'

var tg = require('telegram-node-bot')('mytoken')

tg.router.
    when(['/start'], 'StartController')

tg.controller('StartController', ($) => {
    tg.for('/start', () => {
        $.sendMessage('Hi, welcome to my bot!') //notice the dollar sign
    })
})
```